# BrowserSync prevents navigation in Firefox (OS X)

Tags: javascript, firefox, gulp, browser-sync

I initially tried setting up BrowserSync to proxy my current .dev site.
I had the following issues:

- Page loads were really, *really* slow.
- In Firefox (but not in Safari), when I clicked any link, the current page would reload rather than following the link.

I then changed to manually embedding the snippet. Not ideal, but it solved the speed issue - and interestingly it seemed to *partly* solve the navigation blocking issue, too.

Now it only blocks about half the time. It seems to me that if the page takes less than half a second or so to load, it's fine, but if it takes more than that BrowserSync stops it and reloads the current page.
(This explains why disabling the proxy partly fixed it, since with the proxy pages always took around 20s to load.)

I have tried this in normal Firefox 34, and in a fairly clean install of Firefox Dev Edition 36, with almost no extensions installed. (I disabled the LiveReload extension in case that was causing the problem. It wasn't.)
As I mentioned, it works fine in Safari on the same machine... which seems odd.

I am running BrowserSync via gulp.

gulpfile.js (with some irrelevant parts omitted for clarity):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browsersync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browsersync.reload;

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
        .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    browsersync({online: false});
    gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('**/*.php', reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of old, but I had the same issue as well. I did not get a resolution, but I asked the author, and he had me do some tests using a non-wordpress html file. Here is his answer: https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/435#issuecomment-73732362

I am still boggled on why this doesn't work only in Firefox. In chrome, and other browsers, they link through fine. It seems like it's something in firefox though, just don't know what.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. I have left a comment on that issue linking to my report here, in case it helps the developer to fix it (if he is interested, which it looks like he is not from his reaction to your report).
It's certainly strange that the bug only affects Firefox. Sadly, since Firefox is my primary browser, it means BrowserSync is not usable for me.

Comment: @Caesar - Thanks for taking this issue further, I didn't even think to try slowing down my webpage loads (I know you didn't do that, but I can try that out and see). I have a program called Charles Proxy, and I can limit the bandwidth so it slows down the page. Maybe I will try that on a regular HTML file to see if the clicks register. To be honest with you, BrowserSync is awesome, and I could not find anything better, so I just got in to the habit of just holding CTRL and clicking on a link to open a new tab. It then works fine! Not a useful solution, but I can still use browsersync in FF